# how to fill the cpu cache forcefully

Tags: bash, cpu, benchmarking, cpu-cache

Is there a simple (bash based) way to forcefully fill up the cpu cache with some dummy contents? I am comparing the timings of two programs and would need to make sure the cache content is flushed after a program execution, and before running the other program.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to execute a typical problem that have a lot of CPU-bound instructions, computing the number PI. Here you are, is a little script that is executed by bc

```
#!/usr/bin/bc -l
scale=3000
pi=4*a(1)
quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good tool is stress-ng, which has a streaming mode to stress CPU cache by streaming random data into cache.

```
stress-ng --stream 4 --stream-l3-size 2M --perf --metrics-brief -t 60
```